# Proving that the Hilbert scheme of points on $\mathbb C^2$ is smooth

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hilbert-schemes

On a summer school for undergraduate and graduate students Okounkov gave the following exercise (without hints): Prove that the Hilbert scheme of points on $\mathbb C^2$ is smooth.

Only a definition of the scheme was given. I don't really understand how to solve this exercise.

I remember Beauville was saying in his course on a school at Lac de Garde (while he was commenting page 14 here: http://math1.unice.fr/~beauvill/conf/lacgarde2.pdf), that he is not aware of an elementary proof of the fact that the Hilbert scheme of points on a smooth surface is smooth (a standard proof uses $Ext$ groups).

So I would like to know, who is right, Okounkov or Beauville? (or maybe both?...)

Comment: Do you know about $Ext$ groups?

Comment: Depends on what is meant by "know". I red the definition 20 times over the span of my life. I can calculate these groups in some simple examples. But since I still have not read Hartchorne beyond section 1, maybe the honest answer should be: NO.

Comment: There are many proofs of this result--one using Ext groups is in FGA Explained, in the chapter on Hilbert schemes of points.  It's not actually that bad, in my opinion.  I believe one can also prove this result (more elementarily) using the description of the Hilbert scheme as a space of commuting matrices.

Comment: I think there's a proof that goes like this. Let $T = (\mathbb C^\times)^2$ act on the plane hence on the Hilbert scheme. Then any point has a $T$-fixed point in the closure of its $T$-orbit, hence it's enough to check smoothness at the $T$-fixed points. For each of those, you can figure out what $Hom_R(I,R/I)$ looks like as a $T$-representation, and in particular that it is $2n$-dimensional. Which is to say, no $Ext^{i>0}$ is considered.

Comment: Allen, thank you this is interesting. I wonder why this does not work in dimension 3. As far as I remember, even the dimension of the Hilbert scheme of points of $\mathbb C^3$ is unknown for large number of points

Comment: The proof Allen sketches is written out in detail in chapter 18.2 of Miller and Sturmfels <i>Combinatorial Commutative Algebra</i>. It's elementary, but it's not easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to get the smoothness fro free is by using the description of the Hilbert scheme as a quiver variety. Since it is a result of the hyperkahler reduction applied to a flat variety and the parameter of the reduction is regular (in this case regularity is just its nonvanishing), it is smooth.

Comment: Sasha, could you give me some good reference for this?

Comment: I think the best reference is the Nakajima's book.